# Calculate conditional probability using mean and variance

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, variance, means

I have a set where its values follow a normal distribution, but I only have the sum of all of them, and the sum of its squares.

Having: $\sum_{i=0}^n X_i$ and $\sum_{i=0}^n X_i^2$.

I have the following "table":

```
((+ (fever 245 5975))
 (- (fever 176 4540)))
```

There are two types of classes: Positive (+) and Negative(-). For both, I have the sum (245 and 176), and the sum of their squares (5975 and 4540).

How can I calculate P(Positive class given 45)?

P(Positive class given 45) or $P(Positive|45)$ means that given a fever of 45, it will be positive case and the patient will have measles. This is an invented example.

I think I have to use the mean and the variance, but I don't know how.

Comment: What does "$P(Positive|25)$" mean?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Sorry, but your table is unreadable. Please fix it. Additional it seems that you´ve omitted some context.

Comment: @callculus I don't think so. I'm only asking if it is possible to calculate conditional probability with the mean and the variance.

Comment: @VansFannel If you think so. But I can tell you that´s not right. It can be only guessed what is meant.

Comment: Just trying to understand your problem in my own way here. You have calculated the mean and variance of $n$ samples drawn from two different normal distributions without knowing which is which. You are now trying to ascertain which samples correspond to which distribution. By $P(+|45)$, you mean the probability that the samples come from one of the distributions given that the mean or variance is 45?

Comment: This question is really unclear to me.  What do the $X_i$ represent?  What does $n$ represent?  I'm guessing that the positive class is *actually* positive for some condition (say, measles), and the negative class is *actually* negative for that condition; is that right?  Why do you think that the $X_i$ are normally distributed?  (You probably shouldn't use "fever" as an example, since a fever of $45$ means DEAD whether you're talking F or C.)

Comment: P.S.  I suppose a "fever" of $45$ F has been known to occur in people who have survived because of being in kind of a state of suspended animation?  Not my specialty...

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to hazard a guess as to what you mean, in ordinary terms.  I'm going to guess that you have two normal distributions, with estimated means $\mu_c$ (class $c = 1, 2$) and standard deviations $\sigma_c$.  These can be derived from the sum and sum of squares, provided that you know $n$ (for each class, if they're different).

The estimated mean is

$$
\mu = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$$

and the estimated standard deviation is

$$
\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\right) - n\mu^2}{n-1}}
$$

We can then use the PDF of the normal distribution at a given value $x$ to compute the relative likelihoods of being positive or negative for the condition:

$$
f_c(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_c^2}}\exp\left[-\frac{(x-\mu_c)^2}{2\sigma_c^2}\right]
$$

Then I think the probability you want is

$$
P(\text{class $c$} \mid x) = \frac{p_cf_c(x)}{p_1f_1(x)+p_2f_2(x)} \qquad c = 1, 2
$$

where $p_c$ is the *a priori* probability of being in class $c$.

Comment: Probably the right guess.  :)  A possible extra twist is I wouldn't be surprised if the no. of samples in each class is different, i.e. $n_1, n_2$...  Then you can either use a likelihood approach, or even consider the ratio $n_1 : n_2$ to be a prior and use Bayesian.  BTW your final formula ... wouldn't it evaluate to $>1$ in some cases?

Comment: @antkam: Oops, yeah, I forgot the $p_c$!  Thanks for the catch.  Incidentally, I didn't think of using $n_1 : n_2$ as a prior, since I think it's not likely to be appropriate.  But perhaps...

Comment: Who said anything about _appropriate_?  This sounds like a game of "lets guess what the teacher / examiner had in mind" ;)